# Can't resolve dependency, refering to root project - next@"^9.5.6-canary.13, next-routes@"^1.4.2"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I am trying for hours to resolve this issue, running from one error to the next one…
Trying everything from --legacy-peer-deps, --force npm audit fix, at this point I am not even able to install my packages without running into errors, and I don't understand what that error is saying:

```
npm ERR! Found: next@9.5.6-canary.18
npm ERR! node_modules/next
npm ERR!   next@"^9.5.6-canary.13" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer next@">=2" from next-routes@1.4.2
npm ERR! node_modules/next-routes
npm ERR!   next-routes@"^1.4.2" from the root project
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "next dev",
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.19",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.9",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "framer-motion": "^4.0.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "ignore-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "lazysizes": "^5.3.2",
    "next": "^9.5.6-canary.13",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "node-webvtt": "^1.9.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.6",
    "storyblok-js-client": "^4.0.5",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.13",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  }
}
```

I am guessing some of the longer list of packages are not playing along with each other, but how can I investigate this further? The error is not very helpful. Also the similar combinations of packages and version seem to work fine in other projects …
The error originally complained about graphql packages I am using, after updating some versions it is now complaining about the next and next-routes packages …

Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you're using an old canary version of Next.js? Have you tried using a stable version like `9.5.5` or `10.0.0` instead?

Comment: I was trying multiple version of next, this version was working in one of my other projects. I have now resolved the issue, but I am not sure which was the relevant step.
At some point it worked after reinstalling next with the --legace-peer-deps flag.